# How to check HTML element height as rendered by webkit but in the backend?

Tags: php, browser, headless

I have a form that takes a WYSIWYG input. This is to be rendered as is on the front end but its height cannot exceed a certain limit when rendered. I need to verify that it'll be within that limit once submitted to my PHP script.

Of course I can check in the front-end by JS but I cannot trust client-side verification for this.

What I've tried:

- used DOMPDF to create a PDF
- Exported it as PNG

The element has a border around it as rendered by DOMPDF. The only thing I can think of now is to measure the bounding box by PHP and verify that the height is within the limit.

I know that the DOM can be recreated from the markup in PHP but I still won't be able to get the height of a rendered element.

What I'd prefer is a headless browser of some sort that'll let me do this:

```
$page = $browser->make($markup);
$height = $page->getElementById('element_id')->height;
```

Is there a pure-PHP (i.e. non-PhantomJS) solution for something like this?

Comment: I'm very, very curious about why you'd want to know that. I just can't imagine a single reason for it (as you could set `overflow: hidden` on the containing `<div>` tag). Could you elaborate on that? For a headless browser of some sort, I'd investigate [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) as a possible option. It still requires a locally installed browser, though.

Comment: I understand what you mean, it's just a very very specific use-case. I'd do the `overflow:hidden` method but it'll mess with the presentation somewhat. I ended up parsing the generated PDF doc to get the dimensions of the bounding box. Works well for now. :)

Comment: It may be wise then to add that as an answer and accept it, so people don't spend time thinking up another way. ;)